# I am not able to transfer my username and password from one jframe to another

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, netbeans-7

**EmailClient.java**

```
package sendemail;

    public class EmailClient extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        SendMail sm=new SendMail();
        Settings set=new Settings();
        public EmailClient() {
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated code                     

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
           // TODO add your handling code here:
            sm.setVisible(true);
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jMenuItem2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            set.setVisible(true);
        }                                          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    new EmailClient().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
        private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu4;
        private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu5;
        private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar2;
        private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
```

**Settings.java**

```
package sendemail;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    public class Settings extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        public String uname;
        public String pass;
        public String smtpserver;
        public String  port;
        /**
         * Creates new form Settings
         */
        public Settings() {
            initComponents();
        }

        public String getUname() {
            return uname;
        }

        public String getPass() {
            return pass;
        }

        public String getSmtpserver() {
            return smtpserver;
        }

        public String getPort() {
            return port;
        }



        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated Code                   

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
           uname=jTextField1.getText().toString();
            pass=jPasswordField1.getPassword().toString();

            smtpserver=jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString();
            port=jComboBox2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            if(uname.equals("") || pass.equals("") || smtpserver.equals("") || port.equals("") )
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"All Fields are mandatory");
        }                                        
        else
            {
                setVisible(false);
            }

        }                                        

        private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                          

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Settings().setVisible(false);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
        private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

**SendMail.Java**

```
package sendemail;

    import java.util.Properties;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;


    public class SendMail extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        Settings setfrm=new Settings();
        String subject;
        String from;

        public SendMail() {
            initComponents();
        }


        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        +Generated Code                    

        private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            try
            {
            final String user=setfrm.getUname();
            final String password=setfrm.getPass();
            String portnum=setfrm.getPort();
            String smtpname=setfrm.getSmtpserver();
            String to=jTextField1.getText();
            subject=jTextField2.getText();
            Properties properties=new Properties();
            properties.put("mail.smtp.host",smtpname.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port",portnum.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            properties.put("mail.smtp.port",portnum.toString());
            properties.put("mail.smtp.auth","true");
            Session session=Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
               new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                   protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication(){
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user,password);

               }

               }

               );
            MimeMessage message=new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(jTextField1.getText().toString()));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(jTextArea1.getText());
            Transport.send(message);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"message sent");
            }
            catch(MessagingException mex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,mex);
            }
        }                                        

        private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                        

        private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            // TODO add your handling code here:
        }                                           

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            /* Create and display the form */
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new SendMail().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }

        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
        private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
        private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
        private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
        private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
        private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
        private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
        // End of variables declaration                   

    }
```

**Error**

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:306)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.connect(SMTPTransport.java:93)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at sendemail.SendMail.jButton1ActionPerformed(SendMail.java:189)
    at sendemail.SendMail.access$100(SendMail.java:25)
    at sendemail.SendMail$2.actionPerformed(SendMail.java:77)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3311)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 42 seconds)
```

**I have seen that that the problem lies only within the transfering of values from one frame to another.The values for username and password are accepted in Settings.java and transfered to SendEmail.java**

Comment: Paste only relevant code to start of. People will not look through bunch of code if its not relevant to the problem. As a side note ? Why you do  ...extends java.swing.JFrame ? instead of just JFrame ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two different instances of `Settings` class - one in `SendMail`, the other in `EmailClient`. Changing one instance will not affect the other. Create a constructor in `SendMail` that accepts a `Settings` instance:

```
public SendMail(Settings settings) {
    this.setfrm = settings;
    initComponents();
}
```

and edit initialisation of `SendMail` in `EmailClient`:

```
Settings set=new Settings();
SendMail sm=new SendMail(set);

public EmailClient() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Thus, you make sure that both `SendMail` and `EmailClient` use one and the same `Settings` instance (google about references in Java for more information).

Comment: How to get the username and password from Settings.java to SendMail.java?

Comment: You should know it better since it's your code :-) I can only assume that the method `Settings.getUname()` returns the name. Now you have an instance of `Settings` type in your `SendMail` class which you access by `setfrm` field. So, your call would be e.g. `String userName = setfrm.getUname();`. The same with password. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I saw that in SendEmail.java , you create a new instance of Settings --> so that the username & password will be null.
Then you start SendEmail jframe and access to username & email --> failed.
I think you need to do like this:
- You define 2 string variable to store username & password 
In the SendEmail jframe you have a button to open Settings jframe to set your own username & password--> update changed to username & password in SendEmail :)

Comment: sorry i didn't get you....can you please show me where should i make the necessary changes?